# How to validate a URL in inside a paragraph using Regex

Tags: regex, validation, url

I am using the following regex to validate the URL:

`/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/`

But I'm unable to validate the URL inside a paragraph like this:

> Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the u [www.example.com](https://www.example.com) and and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.

Here it is unable to detect `example.com`.

Can someone provide the regex to validate the URL in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

> Well there are some things you need to understand about RegEx.

`^` - Is a anchor to starting of string.

`$` - Is a anchor to end of string.

When you use `/^some regex$/` it will match only if string is "some regex" not anything else than this. (" some regex"  event this will not be matched because of space at start)

```js
let str = "Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the u www.example.com and and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph."

let reg = /(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?/gi
let op = str.match(reg, str);
console.log(op);
```

You can read here more about this. https://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html